# Django: How to include a block site wide?

Tags: django, templates, block

Apologies, this is pretty basic.  I have abstracted my static html navigation bar to a block so that it can be dynamically rendered from a model.  I have created a new block marker in base.html with the following syntax

```
{% block navigation %}{% endblock %}
```

How can I ensure this is rendered on every page?  Do I need to create some sort of middle layer for this?  Everything I have done so far has simply used the primary block.

**EDIT** Sunday, 14 August 2011 11:25 AM

I didn't explain this very well.  The content of navigation block is

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block navigation %}

<nav>
    <ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>

{% endblock %}
```

I want to render this on every page without having to go through child templates of base.html individually and add it to them, if that is possible.

Comment: You block isn't doing anything here. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got static navigation bar, so you can just write code in your base.html page and then use it with `{% extends 'base.html' %}` tag on every new page. Your markup will be in every page. Also, if you use only extends tag in your child page and then render it - you will see base.html without any edition.

If you have got code, which need to appear on few pages, but not on everyone - create 'includes' directory, save code there and extend your base template with `{% include %}` tag. It won't avoid repating, but make your code shorter.

And last thing you'll need in future, maybe with dynamic code - caching. With `{% cache %}` tag you can cache block for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Your block is not doing anything here, but if you want something to appear in all the templates, you have to define it in a base template (base.html) and make the others extend from it:

base.html

```
Yor menu and the stuff you want to appear everywhere
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

Another template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
The actual content of the page
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

{% block FOO %}{% endblock %} reserves a space to be overwritten in sub templates.

{% include "foo.html" %} pulls content from another file into the current file.

To get {% block navigation %}{% endblock %} to display on every page, you need to add content

```
{% block navigation %}SHOW ME{% endblock %}
```